# Counting strings with 7 letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

With the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

a. How many strings can you make with 5 characters?

b. maximum 7 characters?

c. 4 characters, no repetition?

d. sorted strings without repetition. Sorted = alphabetical.

e. sorted strings with 7 characters.

I think I got a-d solved, so no need to explain those too much.
However, please do explain how you got the answer for e, in a way I could figure out similar questions later.

EDIT:

I tried messing around some with 'e' and got a question equal to something a machine told me. Used formula $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1} \left(\binom{7+7-1}{7-1}= 1716\right)$ to get there. I'm not sure why what I did was right though.

Thanks for any reply. Sorry of I messed up anything about this question.

Comment: Is there a typo on e.?

Comment: It appears so. Fixed it.

Comment: Before I post my full solution, I would like to clarify. What do you mean by "sorted strings"? Do you mean A must come before B, C, D, E, F, or G, B must come before C, D, E, F, or G, etc.?

Comment: Yes. Sorted, meaning alphabetical.

Comment: And you may repeat?

Comment: Unless stated that you can't repeat then you can repeat.

Answer (score 0):

**a.** Assuming you may repeat, there are $7$ choices for each of the five slots, so the answer is $7^5$.

**b.** This is just $7^0+7^1+\cdots+7^7$.

**c.** There are $7$ choices for the first slot, $6$ for the second slot, $5$ for the third slot, and $4$ for the last slot, so the answer is $$ 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4. $$

**d.** Unclear. How many letters?

**e.** Waiting for clarification. Will edit in when I find out.

Comment: 'd' has no repetition, so I guess it's maximum 7 characters.

Comment: What needs to be clarified on 'e'?

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $7$ into $7$ parts.  Each element of the composition tells you how many of that letter are in your string, and the order is set because the string is sorted.  For example, the composition 4,2,0,0,0,1,0 would correspond to the string AAAABBF