# Counting more strings with 7 letter

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Already made one sort of like this earlier ([Counting strings with 7 letters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534655/counting-strings-with-7-letters)), but I'm still not getting into the mindset required for this kind of tasks.

Anyway, I'm given the letters A-G

and..

1. I need to figure out how many strings I can make with a length from 5 to 10 that has an odd number of Bs (1B, 3Bs, etc.)

What I did here so far is figuring out how many ways I can place the Bs (1^5 for 1B and length of 5) and then adding in how many ways I can add in the other letters in the remaining positions (6^4).

But this: a. Sounds wrong to me. With 5 positions there's no way there's only 1 way to do it.. right?

and b. It's a large answer that in the end gets added together. (at least 3 ways for each length of the string (length of 5: 1B, 3Bs, 5Bs)). I'm just feeling it's too large to be the right answer.

. 2. Need to find amount of sorted strings (alphabetical) with a maximum length of 10 with at least one A, at least three Es and maximum 2 Bs.

I'm not sure where to even start here. I'd assume to "loop" through all possible combinations (1A, 2A, 3A, etc.. 3E, 4E, etc.. You get the point.) But it seems like there's some easier way to do this.

If anyone knows where to read up on how to get into this mindset, then a link would be appreciated.

Edit: I guess I need to add what I've already learnt:
C(m, n), P(m, n), m^n, C(m+n-1, n-1),
rule of sum, rule of addition, rule of bijection (I don't get how they convert the task into binary and then count zeroes for the answer though.), factorial.
I think that's all that's relevant to this.

Anyway, thanks for any replies.

Comment: 1. With 5 positions, there are 5 ways to put 1 B. In general, with $n$ positions, there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to put $m$ B's.
2. This is quite tricky and messy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

The number of ways to put $m$ B's in $n$ positions is $\binom nm$. Then you are left with $n - m$ positions to fill with A, C, D, E, F, G. There are $6^{n-m}$ ways to do this. The answer is then
$$
\sum_{n=5}^{10}\left(\binom n16^{n-1} + \binom n36^{n-3} + \binom n56^{n-5} + \binom n76^{n-7} + \binom n96^{n-9}\right)
$$
where you consider $\binom nm = 0$ when $m > n$.
(More concisely, it's $\sum_{n=5}^{10} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor(n + 1)/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k - 1}6^{n - 2k + 1}$.)

2)

This can be done by the [stars and bars method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), but you have to deal with extra constraints yourself. A brief explanation of the method: think about the positions of AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FG in the string. Letters in the string are "stars", and the "bars" can be seen as separators between groups of the same letter (A|B, B|C, C|D, and so on). A sorted string is essentially determined by these positions.

To apply the method, first add another alphabet, say H, to fill in the string of length < 10 and make its length exactly 10.

Then we deal with the condition on B's. If we have exactly $n$ B's, the problem is equivalent to reducing the length of the string to $10 - n$, and removing B from the alphabet set. So we split into three cases: 0, 1 and 2 B's.

Now, assume we are dealing with the subproblem with exactly $n$ B's. We need to find the number of sorted strings made from A, C, D, E, F, G, H of length $10 - n$ such that at least 1 A and 3 E's occur. The conditions on the numbers of A's and E's can be easily dealt with. Just remove 1 A and 3 E's from any valid string. The result will be shorter by $4$. The problem is now reduced to finding sorted strings of length $6 - n$, still with the character set A, C, D, E, F, G, H.

Let's look at the stars and bars method again. Suppose we have a string ACDGG. This corresponds to the picture

$$
\text{. A | C | D ||| G . G |}
$$
where | are the *bars* corresponding to transitions AC, CD, DE, EF, FG, GH in this order, and . are *gaps* not occupied by any bars. The stars and bars method does not work directly with this problem as many bars (like EF, FG, GH in this example) can go to the same *gap*, but if we add 1 letter to each each group, two bars cannot go to the same gap:

$$
\text{A . A | C . C | D . D | E | F | G . G . G | H}
$$

The string is longer by 7 letters, which is the size of the alphabet set. It should be clear now how to obtain different strings by moving bars around. If the original string is of length $6 - n$, this extended string would have length $13 - n$, and the number of gaps between letters will be $12 - n$. The number of bars is 6. The number of ways to place 6 bars in $12 - n$ places is $\binom{12-n}6$.

(To get back the original string, remove one occurrence of each alphabet, remove all H's, and add 1 A, 3 E's, and n B's.)

Therefore, the answer to this problem is
$$
\binom{12}6 + \binom{11}6 + \binom{10}6
$$

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain my "mindset" for solving (a). The first thing to do (as you have tried to do) is to simplify the problem. We are looking for $$A = \mbox{The number of strings from length $5$ to $10$ that has an odd number of $B$s in it.}$$
So let's try to do it this way. Define
$$A_i = \mbox{The number of strings of length $i$ that has an odd number of $B$s in it.}$$
First convince yourself that we have: $$A = A_5 + A_6 + \cdots + A_{10}.$$
Now we do one more step of simplification via defining
$$A_{i,j} = \mbox{The number of strings of length $i$ that has $j$ $B$s in it.}$$
We now have
$$A_5 = A_{5,1}+A_{5,3}+A_{5,5},$$
$$A_6 = A_{6,1}+A_{6,3}+A_{6,5},$$
$$A_7 = A_{7,1}+A_{7,3}+A_{7,5}+A_{7,7}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$A_{10} = A_{10,1}+A_{10,3}+\cdots+A_{10,9}.$$
We then just need to calculate $A_{i,j}$ to get what we want. Now, suppose $j=1$, we then need
$$A_{i,1} = \mbox{The number of strings of length $i$ that has $1$ $B$s in it.}$$
Regarding $A_{i,1}$, we have $i$ possible places in our string to put B. Once we have decided where to put $B$, for each of the remaining $i-1$ places, we have $6$ possible choices. Therefore, $A_{i,1} = i6^{i-1}$. (As an example, if $i=3$, we consider an empty string of the form XXX. We can put $B$ to the first place, which gives us BXX, for the remaining two $X$s we have $6^2$ choices. We can put $B$ to the second place, which gives us $XBX$, and again we have $6^2$ choices for the $X$s, and so on.)

In order to calculate $A_{i,j}$ for general $i$ and $j \leq i$, we proceed in the same manner by first calculating the number of different ways we can put the $j$ $B$s in our string.

To gain some intuition on this more difficult case, suppose we are calculating $A_{4,2}$. We may, for example, put the $B$s to the first and the second place. I represent this choice via the set $\{1,2\}$. Well, we may put the $B$s to the second and the fourth place. I represent this choice via the set $\{2,4\}$. The possibilities (on where to put our $2$ $B$s) can then be represented by the sets $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}$. The key here is to realize that these possible choices regarding where to put $B$s are in fact the $2$ element subsets of the $4$ element set $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and there are $\binom{4}{2}$ of them. For each of these $\binom{4}{2}$ possibilities on where to put $B$s, you have $6^2$ choices on how to decide on the remaining places of the string. Therefore, $A_{4,2} = \binom{4}{2}6^2$.

In general, you should be able to show (and understand) that $A_{i,j} = \binom{i}{j}6^{i-j}$. The rest is writing $A$ in a summation form. One possible form is
$$A = \sum_{i=5}^{10} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (i-1)/2 \rfloor} A_{i,2j+1} = \sum_{i=5}^{10} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (i-1)/2 \rfloor} \binom{i}{2j+1}6^{i-2j-1},$$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Answer (score 0):

You can break this down into computing two easier numbers. If $N(s,b)$ is the number of such strings of length $s$ and containing $b$ instances of the character 'B', then you can compute $N(s,b)$ as
$$
    N(s,b) = B(s,b) \cdot W(s-b),
$$
where $B(s,b)$ is the number of ways to place $b$ B's in a string of length $s$ and $W(s-b)$ is the number of strings of length $s-b$ containing only the characters A, C, D, E, F, and G.

For example, to compute $N(5,1)$, note there are $5$ possible ways to place $1$ $B$ in a string of length $5$, and $W(5-1) = W(4) = 6^4$. So $N(5,1) = 5 \cdot 6^4$. Try to come up with the general form of $B(s,b)$ and $W(s-b)$. (If you don't see the pattern, you will after computing them for a few more values of $s$ and $b$, like $(s,b) = (5,3), (5,5), (6,1)$.) Once you know these, you know the general form of $N(s,b)$, and your answer will be a sum over all applicable $N(s,b)$.